# John has a ball and Jack a bat

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses, conjunction-reduction

Is "John has a ball and Jack a bat" correct?

Could you also help me complete the following:

- John, Jack: subjects
- ball, bat: objects
- has: [?]
- a: article

What are all the four categories called together besides words?

Comment: What do you think it might be?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It seems to me that it is correct because the expression is clear.

Comment: I am asking about your second question, that is, 'what part of speech is 'has'?

Comment: Discarding the repeated **verb** *(**has**)* in this *exact* example would be *more* likely in a formal or literary context, and *less* likely in a relaxed conversational context. Which is a relatively unusual type of stylistic difference - usually, it's the other way around (*shorter* phrasing is often characteristic of *informal* utterances).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's grammatically valid. It's an example of *gapped coordination*, sometimes called *gapping*.  It only works when both verbs are exactly the same, and if so, the verb can then be omitted. Note that you are more likely to find this construction in literary English than in spoken/colloquial English.

> John has a ball and Jack [has] a bat.

More examples

> She likes cats, and he [likes] dogs
>
> John ate the bread, and Sally [ate] the salad.
>
> He took the train, and she [took] the bus.

You can't use it if the verbs have different meanings

> He has money, and she [has] to go home. ❌

For more info, see this article [Grammatical Coordination](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-coordination-grammar-1689931)

Comment: I noticed that you have put a comma between the two clauses in all the examples. Is it because the clauses are independent?

Comment: @aminta - Depends how you look at it, but it is a general convention to use a comma before a coordinating conjunction.  So I'm just going to say yes.